# error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

Q. Write a program that 'bleeps' out words that you don't like; that is, you read in words using cin and print them again on cout. If a word is among a few you have defined, you write out BLEEP instead of that word. (stroustrup's c++ book)

Here's the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }
int main() 
{
  vector<string> disliked;
  disliked.push_back("Broccoli");
  disliked.push_back("Carrots");
  disliked.push_back("Tomatoes");
  disliked.push_back("Asparagus");

  vector<string> words;
  string word;
  while (cin >> word) {
    words.push_back(word);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    cout << words[i] << "\t";     //i used it to see if the program was working
    }
  for (int j = 0; j < disliked.size(); ++j) {
    cout << disliked[j] << "\t";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
     if (words[i] == disliked[j]) {
   cout << "BLEEP";
   }
   else {
   }
  }
}
```

I think the problem arises due to my final for loop, but I don't understand what is to be done.

Here is the error I got:

```
bleep.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bleep.cpp:27:8: error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
bleep.cpp:27:8: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
bleep.cpp:27:19: error: name lookup of ‘j’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: J in undefined because it is defined inside the for.

Comment: Please update your question's title because it gives zero indication of your problem. Note that Stackoverflow is not a forum and functions very differently from one. Read [ask] and [faq] for more info.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
 if (words[i] == disliked[j]) {
  cout << "BLEEP";
 }
 else {
 }
}
```

Here you are using `i` and `j` without declaring them. The previous declarations have only the block scope in which you are declaring. Either you have to redeclare them or if u want to use previous values, declare them above the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared the variable **i** and **j** in the for loop, hence because of the scope issue, you cannot access the variables in another for loop.

From what I have understood, in the final for loop, you are checking whether each word in the **words** array is equal to one of the words in **disliked** array. To do this, you need to use two for loops as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<disliked.size(); j++){
         if(words[i] == disliked[j]){
              words[i] = "BLEEP";     //This step replaces the disliked word with "BLEEP"
           }
    }
}
```

Note : If you declare `int i,j;` before using them in the loops, then you need not declare them again inside any of the for loops.

Comment: it fixes the errors, but it doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: @user3704747 it would be better if you tell what is your problem, I would be very happy to help you